# PHP PDO PGPOOL PGSQL - SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 7 no connection to the server

Tags: postgresql, pdo, pgpool

I try to explain the problem I have!!!

I use PDO extension to connect to PostgreSQL through pgpool-II. It works fine within Apache, but from PHP CLI (on the same machine) I receive this PDO error:

**SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 7 no connection to the server**

I have already searched on Google and here, but it seems that no one has ever tried to do this. Does anyone have any idea?

EDIT:

This is the code I use to establish a connection:

```
include 'manage_db.php';
include_once 'properties.php';
global $properties;

$dsn = 'pgsql:dbname=' . $properties['db_pgpool'] . ';host=localhost;port=' . $properties['port_pgpool'];

try{
   $mgmtDb = new ManageDb($dsn, $properties['username_pgpool'], $properties['password_pgpool']);
} catch (Exception $e) {
   echo 'PDO - Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

ManageDB is my own class that implements some utility functions as well as create the database connection:

```
class ManageDb {
        var $db;

        function ManageDb($dsn, $username, $password){
            $this->db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
            $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }

....
```

Comment: Well, it's saying you don't have a connection to the server. How are you connecting and how do you check it worked would be good information to share.

Comment: When using pgpoll, you need to set the connection in the conf file. Have you tried to access your postgresql server using pgadmin3 ? if it success then i think the problem is in your conf setting.

Comment: Did you solve this ?

Answer (score 4):

Try this

config.database.php

```
<?php
class DatabaseConfig {

    const DBNAME    = 'dbname';
    const HOST      = '123.1.233.123';
    const USER      = 'mysuperuser';
    const PASSWORD  = 'mysupperparrword';
    const PORT      = 5432; 
}
?>
```

class.database.php

```
<?php

include('config.database.php');

class Database {

    protected static $instance = null;

    final private function __construct() {}
    final private function __destruct() {
        self::$instance = null;
    }

    final private function __clone() {}

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (self::$instance === null) {
            try {
                self::$instance = new PDO(
                    'pgsql:host='   . DatabaseConfig::HOST . 
                    ';port='        . DatabaseConfig::PORT . 
                    ';dbname='      . DatabaseConfig::DBNAME . 
                    ';user='        . DatabaseConfig::USER . 
                    ';password='    . DatabaseConfig::PASSWORD
                );
                self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                die('Database connection could not be established.');
            }
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }
    public static function __callStatic($method, $args) {
        return call_user_func_array(array(self::instance(), $method), $args);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This work well, but do not really solve the problem.